# Grab values from string

Tags: php

I have the following string:

`$string = "No+Label+name=Aaron+Smith&No+Label+email=aaron.smith@live.co.uk";`

I'd like some PHP to grab the name and email address values from this string.

I'd originally tried the following but made no progress:

```
$str = "No+Label+name=Aaron+Smith&No+Label+email=aaron.smith@live.co.uk";
preg_match_all('#value=([^\s]+)#', $str, $matches);
echo implode(' ', $matches[1]);
```

I'd essentially like to say:

`echo $string['No+Label+name']; // outputs name`

Comment: Looks like a querystring. Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: This is basically a query string format, so https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php can help you with that. (You'll only have to take into account that it will perform URL decoding, so the `+` will become spaces, in your array keys and the values.)

Comment: Really good point @CBroe - thanks for this. Resolved now :-)

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a great e answer but you can use this if you have this string

```
$str = "No+Label+name=Aaron+Smith&No+Label+email=aaron.smith@live.co.uk";
$temp = explode('+', $str);
$name = explode('=',$temp[2]);
$email = explode('=',$temp[5]);
echo ($name[1]);
echo "<br/>";
echo ($email[1]);
```